# CSS Layout Challenge - Floating/Positioning Elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

Got a layout challenge I'm trying to solve with CSS (if there is a solution). Here's the details and what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

- No JS, pure CSS
- Page width 940px, needs to be responsive
- Box A, B, C, D & E have a set width of 300px
- Box A, B, C & D have a defined height of 352px
- Box F should be 640px with a variable height
- Box E should be able to have a variable height (doesn't need to actually fill the whole space)
- The position of box A and B should have a right margin/padding of 20px
- Needs to be cross-browser compliant and work in IE8

Now, here's the tricky part:

- If box C is removed, box D should take it's place and box E should move up to fill the space left by box D. See below: [image]
- If box B & C is removed, box D should take box B's place and box E should move to the top to fill box C & D's area. See below: [image]
- **EDIT: Only box B & C can be removed.**

Comment: You have been pretty clear to describe your requirement but so far what's the code you wrote to solve it by yourself? Where it doesn't work?

Comment: That's the problem, I've tried various different ways, but none do what I need it to do. That's why I'm reaching out to see if there is even a way to accomplish this with pure CSS. Seems simple upfront, but once you start trying to do it, it's a lot harder to accomplish. Still playing around with it right now, but wanted to reach out to see if neone has ne suggestions.

Comment: Who is “removing” the boxes?

Comment: Doesn't matter who's removing the boxes. It should be dynamic and able to account for boxes being removed. That's the challenge.

Comment: Feel free to move the HTML around as well.

Comment: I'd suggest using nth-child selectors to apply specific CSS to each element. Then if the third one is removed, the fourth item would then be considered the third and would get that CSS.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support nth-child.

Comment: You didn't said what should happend in lower wdth and what will be the break points.

Comment: Don't really care at this point about what happens when it becomes smaller. First just trying to get it to work at normal width. Then I can adjust accordingly with breakpoints as it get's smaller.

Comment: Can only remove box B & C. Here's an example using JS: http://jsfiddle.net/eAELA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does it: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/34XUm/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="a block">A</div>
    <div class="b block">B</div>
    <div class="c block">C</div>
    <div class="d block">D</div>
    <div class="e block">E</div>
    <div class="f block">F</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none !important;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0;
}

.block {
    background: #666;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 352px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.b, .c, .d, .e { margin-left: 20px; }

.e, .f {
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100000px;
    margin-bottom: -100000px;
}

.f {
    width: 640px;
    min-height: 373px; /* Greater than 372px */
    background: #999;
    float:left;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

---

Note that in the following code

```
.e, .f {
    padding-bottom: 100000px;
    margin-bottom: -100000px;
}
```

instead of `100000px`, you must use any value greater than the height of both elements.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. In your example, you're removing box C & D. I need to be able to remove box B & C. What you've done works when removing B, but not C. Thanks though, closer than what I've been able to do. Probably should have been clearer about which boxes could be removed.

Comment: @BenMarshall Oh, true. Fixed in http://jsfiddle.net/34XUm/2/, but box F needs a `min: height` to work in the first case

Comment: Beautiful! Works perfect without the need to use a empty div. Less code is beautiful code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This works (haven't tested in IE8 though)

It uses :

- `display: inline-block;`
- `vertical-align: top;`
- `position: absolute;`
- `float: left;`

Fiddle Demos :

- **[All blocks](http://jsfiddle.net/7FsEt/2/)**
- **[No block C](http://jsfiddle.net/7FsEt/3/)**
- **[No block B and C](http://jsfiddle.net/7FsEt/4/)**

Code :

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"> Box A</div>
  <div class="box">Box B</div>
  <div class="box">Box C</div>
  <div class="box">Box D</div>
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <div class="box">Box E</div>
  <div class="content">
    Box F
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 960px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper div {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 352px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.dummy,
.content {
  width: 640px;
}

.dummy {
  float: left;
  height: 373px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 372px;
  left: 0;
  width: 640px;
}
```

Comment: Pretty darn close. Only thing with that is .dummy defines a specific height. Great idea using that to push content over for box F, but box F's height could be variable which means .dummy would need to be variable. Making it variable would break what you're doing there. Closet one yet though! Not sure there's a solution to this one, but if nobody else come up with one, I'll mark this one as the answer.

Comment: @BenMarshall yes, the height of `.dummy` div has to be fixed. In my first fiddle, I set it to 601px but it can be smaller : 373px (height of on box + margin-bottom + 1px) I'll update my answer for that.